# Login failed for user 'sc' even after

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, connection

I am trying to run a web application but I just cannot login with a user account (**sc**). I keep getting

> Login failed for user 'sc'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'sc'.

---

I have given the user **sc** the following permissions

[image]

The login Status is **enabled** and permission to connect is also **granted**

---

My connection string -

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="43200" maxRequestLength="104856"   />

  </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <!--<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True" />-->
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;UID=sc;PWD=mystrongpassword;initial catalog=test;"/>

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

User Mapping

[image]

Here is my Event log -

```
Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/19/2016 3:12:31 PM 
Event time (UTC): 7/19/2016 9:42:31 AM 
Event ID: 5512cef4f9054c2093a8899c987115be 
Event sequence: 7 
Event occurrence: 3 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Dashboard-1-131133944396956249 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Dashboard 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\ 
    Machine name: W104QWRX52 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 19332 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SqlException 
    Exception message: Login failed for user 'sc'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.PrepareCommand(SqlCommand command, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters, Boolean& mustCloseConnection)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText)
   at Helper.getProductCount() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\App_Code\helper.cs:line 44
   at charts_ProductCount.GenerateProductCountChart() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 24
   at charts_ProductCount.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 18
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/Dashboard/Home.aspx 
    Request path: /Dashboard/Home.aspx 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 14 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.PrepareCommand(SqlCommand command, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters, Boolean& mustCloseConnection)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText)
   at Helper.getProductCount() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\App_Code\helper.cs:line 44
   at charts_ProductCount.GenerateProductCountChart() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 24
   at charts_ProductCount.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\charts\ProductCount.ascx.cs:line 18
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

I've been through several posts suggesting to create user/assign permission/change connection string etc but none has helped so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this? -> `<add key="ConnectionString" value="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;user id=sc;password=mystrongpassword;initial catalog=test;"/>`

Comment: Have you mapped the user to the database in the User Mapping section?

Comment: @SujeetSinha Same error.

Comment: @Momar Yes it mapped to my test DB

Comment: Because it thinks the db is local is the picture from your PC or from the server?

Comment: It is local. Everything is on my system.  IIS, Visual Studio, SSMS etc

Comment: Have you tried logging in as that user using SSMS?

Comment: @MartinBrown Yes. First step was to check if the user is working or not.

Comment: Can you show us C# code that actually makes the connection? Have you checked it is getting the correct string out of the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Just running through a list of checks you can do here:

- Check that the login is working correctly. So can you log into SQL Management Studio with the 'sc' user?
- Check that the problem is not specific to this user. Does the connection string work with another user and only fails for the 'sc' user?
- If any user fails, we can assume the issue is not with the login but in another place which could be the Code attempting to connect, Configuration for IIS, Windows firewall or SQL Server. Maybe look into the application pool or server protocol configurations.

Also, the error code is 3005 (ErrorHttpAttemptConnect) description is 'Cannot attempt a connect due to network error'. So maybe try increasing the connection timeout.

Lastly, I would say check the common connection problems online. 
This may be a good start: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

Comment: I can login into SSMS via sc. I have tried with different users as well. Application pool is defaultAppPool which I configured yesterday. Databse is connecting but login is failing. Regarding 3005 as you can see, i have already increased the timeout in connection string

Comment: Just to clarify, the web application is connecting to sql server with another user but not when using user 'sc'?

Comment: no it is not connecting with any other user as well.

Comment: Just noticed you are using LocalDB and not SQL Server Express so maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308654/iis-connecting-to-localdb