# Can't connect to SQL localDB instance from application running on IIS service

Tags: iis, iis-8, localdb, sql-server-2019

I am trying to run DotNetNuke application on the IIS of developer machine.

When the application starts it fails to connect to SQL server. 
This error pops on event log:

> source: SQLLocalDB 14.0
>
> Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects
>      returned error code: 575. Windows system error message is:
>     {Application Error} The application was unable to start correctly
>      (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application. Reported at line: 3714.

At the instance folder i found this or error.log file:

```
2020-04-08 18:43:59.07 spid52      Starting up database 'dnn_platform'.
2020-04-08 18:43:59.10 spid52      Parallel redo is started for database 'dnn_platform' with worker pool size [1].
2020-04-08 18:43:59.11 spid52      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'dnn_platform' with worker pool size [1].
```

The application pool is set to load user profile.
The localDb instance folder has access to anyone write there.

I can't figure what is wrong.

My machine is a windows 10.

Comment: It looks a bit hard to find the root cause based on the error message. Have you tried to capture crash dump with debug diagnostic tool and check what the inner exception is?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access localDb service the user profile must be fully load.
Unfortunally, to fully enable user profile load on IIS it is needed to edit the `applicationhost.config` at `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`.
To do so :

1. create a new application pool by adding this too `applicationhost.config`

   `setProfileEnvironment` can't be set by IIS Management console so that why you have to edit this file
2. On the IIS Management Console change the `localDbCompatiblePool` pool identity to make use of a local or network user
3. Still on IIS Management Console change your Web application or Site settings to use the `localDbCompatiblePool` application pool.

   It maybe be possible to use an user created by Application Pool identity with some more tweaking but i was unable to find out.

Full details on this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13313217/2700303).